# I can't save integer

Tags: java, database, save, sharedpreferences, counter

I Want to save the counter in my application memory and showing it.

I've tried `sharedpreferences` and didn't work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    int counter = 0;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                    
               counter = counter + 1;
               tvCounter.setText(String.valueOf(counter));

            } 
        });
    }

    protected int Counter(View view) {    
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(String.valueOf(counter), 0);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("int value", counter);
        editor.commit();
        sharedPreferences.getInt(String.valueOf(counter), -1);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Counter is working,but application not saving anything.

Comment: Where are you calling your Counter function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharedPreferences save key-value pair.

```
editor.putInt("int value", counter);
```

You are saving value of counter in key "int value".

And trying to retrieve it by wrong key

```
sharedPreferences.getInt(String.valueOf(counter), -1);
```

What you should do instead is

```
sharedPreferences.getInt("int value", -1);
```

I think you are also mixing up preferences file name. To cut confusion use final String's in the class scope.

```
private final String prefsFileName = "counterFile"; // file name for your shared preferences.
private final String counterKey = "counter"; // key to identify counter in your preferences.
```

To save counter value to shared preferences create a method.

```
 private boolean saveCounter(int counter){
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefsFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt(counterKey, counter);
    return editor.commit();
}
```

To get counter value from shared preferences use another method.

```
private int getCounterValue() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefsFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return prefs.getInt(counterKey, -1);
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer,didn't work but i make progressed in project

Comment: happy that you progressed in project, but if the answer didn't worked then tell me more about it, we should make it work.

Comment: I have a counter in my app,counting when I click the button and I want to save the value of counter.My english is not too good,sorry.

Comment: Your English is okay! You have declared sharedPreferences at the top but where have you initialized it?